# The parameters of tolerance scheme of a FIR filter

Tags: filters, filter-design, finite-impulse-response

in the first part of the problem they told us that an FIR filter with impulse response h[k] ( z-trafo H(z) l should be designed to the following parameters.

And then in the second part it says that there is an alternative realisation of a two identical FIR filter of lower order j[k]  thus F(z) = J(z)·J(z) (multiplied ) **and the question is to find the new parameters of j**.

So does it mean that F(z) filter should be equal to the one of H(z) ( i mean they have the same tolerance parameters )? But with a different filter order?

Comment: so, I mean, this might sound a bit trivial, but why don't you take the point-wise square root of $H(z)$?

Comment: You are talking about the parameters right ? If so yeah i took the square root of the approximation error but i wasn't sure if that what they actually meant ! And the filter order of F would be = filter order of j + filter order of j ? Or am i wrong ?

Comment: no, I mean you have $H(z)$ from the first part of the problem. Does $J(z) =\sqrt{H(z)}$ help you? Because that way, $F(z) = J(z)\cdot J(z) = \sqrt{H(z)}\cdot \sqrt{H(z)} = H(z)$ and that fulfills the requirement of being an alternative realization of $H(z)$.

Comment: Yeah thank you so much  i know that but my question was about how would the parameter of tolerance and filter order change ! Sorry for the misunderstanding ^^

Comment: I don't really know what tolerance you're referring to here – and I don't think you can make general statements about the filter order!